How can I make it so that, instead of just vim, it iterates through a list of the names of the packages that I specify?
There is such a playbook:
---
- hosts: [localhost]
  remote_user: "max"
  become: no
  tasks:
    - name: check packages
      package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - name: print
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['vim'][0]['name'] }} is {{ ansible_facts.packages['vim'][0]['version'] }}"

Output:
TASK [print] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: vim is 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17

How can I make it so that, instead of just vim, it iterates through a list of the names of the packages that I specify?

For example, given the list of packages
  packages: [ansible, apache2, python3]

Iterate the packages:

Convert the dictionary ansible_facts.packages to a list.

Select keys from the list of packages.

The dictionary values of ansible_facts.packages are lists because more package versions can be installed. Iterate subelements.


The below declaration
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages |
                dict2items |
                selectattr('key', 'in', packages) |
                subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"

gives
ok: [localhost] => (item=ansible) => 
  msg:
    arch: all
    category: universe/admin
    name: ansible
    origin: Ubuntu
    source: apt
    version: 9.2.0+dfsg-0ubuntu5
ok: [localhost] => (item=python3) => 
  msg:
    arch: amd64
    category: python
    name: python3
    origin: Ubuntu
    source: apt
    version: 3.12.3-0ubuntu1

The package apache2 was not installed.


Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    
    packages: [ansible, apache2, python3]

  tasks:

    - package_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages |
                dict2items |
                selectattr('key', 'in', packages) |
                subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"



you can list your packages in a variable. and then iterate through it.
---
- hosts: [localhost]
  remote_user: "max"
  become: no
  vars:
    packages:
      - vim
      - apache2
      - python3

  tasks:
    - name: Check packages
      package_facts:
        manager: auto

    - name: Print package information
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }} is {{ item.version }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | dict2items | selectattr('value.name', 'in', packages) | map(attribute='value') | list }}"




Thank you for answer, but error: "msg: '''list object'' has no attribute ''name'''"
